# Python and list combination

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python and generaly in programing and got frustrated.
I have a task to done. I need to load file.txt (that have one letter in each row) and then to create another file2.txt with all combinations. This is code I manage to start

```
from itertools import product    
def main():
    list = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
    for word in product(list, repeat=2):
        print (''.join(word))
if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

And it gave me this

```
AA
AB
AC
AD
BA
BB
BC
BD
CA
CB
CC
CD
DA
DB
DC
DD
```

and this one doesnt work.

```
from itertools import product

def main():

    list = open('recnik2.txt', 'a')    #I gess python cant read like this
    for word in product(list, repeat=2):
        print (''.join(word))


if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

It gave me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\"Ideletedthis"\product.py", line 11, in <module>
if __name__ == "__main__": main()
  File "C:\Users\"Ideletedthis"\product.py", line 7, in main
    for word in product(list, repeat=2):
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

Any1 can explain why and maybe give some better solution

Comment: Ummm...why are you trying to read from a file that you opened in append mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operating systems give you multiple options when working with files. One option is to read the contents. Another is to write to it. You usually have to specify each option you'd like to perform in order to do it. This is a safety mechanism.

In your code, you're asking the OS, through Python, to "append" to the `recnik2.txt` file. Append is a way to *write* contents to a file, starting at the end of it. But since you're trying to read from a file that was opened with "write" access only, the OS is telling you that the file "isn't readable."

Try opening opening with "read" access with `open('recnik2.txt', 'r')`. [Read this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) if you're curious about other options.

Comment: well i tought "append" means read file then write at the end.

Comment: @Difermo You were close. Keep pushing. Programming can be very rewarding once you get over that initial frustration.

Comment: I better find some good book. The one I have is very bad!! Once I get python syntax and rules it would be easy. Then it is only learning built in funcions :)

Comment: Take a look at http://learnpythonthehardway.org/ (free online version: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/). It's very practical. If you do read through it, let me know what you think. I'm always interested in what works for new programmers.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to correct that with "read" mode and creating another file with "write". 
But the more I learn the more problems I have. This is the code

```
from itertools import product

def main():

    infile = open('recnik2.txt', 'r')
    outfile = open('recnik3.txt', 'w')
    for word in product(infile, repeat=2):
    print (''.join(word), file=outfile)
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

And it gave this.

```
A
A

A
B

A
C

A
D
B
A

B
B

B
C

B
D
C
A

C
B

C
C

C
D
DA

DB

DC

DD
```

I know that print() must print empty lines that can be delete with end= ''.
But that is line between combination. And that line isn't there when it jumpt to another letter. Look to

```
A
D
B
A
```

B and D doenst have space, so if i put end= '' it will place

```
A
DB
A
```

That's confusing. And why does it separate combinations? Why AA isn't next to each other and DD is yust like I need.
Sorry if I this is noob's question but cant find tutorial that explains this.
Python guide have lots but not sou details